# Headers already sent

Tags: php

при создании авторизации на сайте:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\OSPanel\domains\NewProject.ru\register\connect.php:5) in C:\OSPanel\domains\NewProject.ru\index.php on line 26

Вот мой php код

```
<?
require "register/rb.php";
require "register/connect.php"
?>
        <?php
        $data = $_POST;
        if (isset($data['go-login'])) {
            $error = array();
            $user = R::FindOne('users', 'login = ?', array($data['login']));
            if ($user) {
                if (md5($data['password']) == $user->password) {
                    $_SESSION['login'] = $user;
                } else {
                    $error[] = 'Неверный пароль!';
                }
                } else {
                    $error[] = 'Мы не нашли такого пользователя';
                }
            }
         if (!empty($error)) {
             echo array_shift($error);
         }
     ?> 
        <?
            if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
                header('location:/dashboard');
            };  
             ?>
```

Это единственный файл где отправляется header. Подскажите в чем причина?

Comment: В том, что вы перед этим header отправляете несколько пробелов, что автоматически приводит к отправке стандартных хедеров

Comment: Убрал все пробелы, не помогло

Comment: Пробелы, знаки перевода строки, табуляция тоже считаются.

Comment: @user407430 покажите новый код, и не забыва´те про содержимое файлов rb.php и connect.php которые тоже могут что-нибудь отправляаь

Answer (score 0):

Любой текст, который есть в php-файле, отправляется с заголовками (headers), поэтому перед началом php кола в тегах `<? ... ?>` не должно быть ничего, в том числе лишних пробелов.

Comment: Проверил на наличие пробелв лишних, все убрал, но проблема осталась

Answer (score 0):

Нужно заменить блок кода

```
<?
require "register/rb.php";
require "register/connect.php"
?>
        <?php
        $data = $_POST;
```

на

```
<?
require "register/rb.php";
require "register/connect.php"
        $data = $_POST;
```

так как работа PHP-интерпретатора заканчивается на закрытии тега `?>` - все остальное текст